# What is the most efficient way to rotate and display an image in an Android UI?

Tags: java, android, performance, drawing, image-rotation

I want to **rotate** an **image** often (multiple times a second) and **display** it. In preparation to this, the image must be scaled to fit the View.

What I first did, was defining a Drawable, loading it into a ImageView and calling [setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)). But it's only supportet since API level 11 and not 9.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

This gives a very bad perfomance (as expected), but what is the most effcient/suitable way to do this? The image contains transparent areas, if that is important. Should I use hardware acceleration?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998053/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-draw-a-rotated-bitmap-on-an-android-canvas) answer is somehow related to this topic. But in my case, the rotation has to be done multiple times while the scaling has to be done only once.

I am stuck at this point after I worked on it for quite a while, and seek assistance here. Please comment if you have further questions, I will happily answer them.

Comment: Is this rotation a constant animation, or is the rotation angle controlled by user gestures, or... ?

Comment: It is controlled by a sensor, so it is **not constant**. @kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your sensor reading is a *push* model, where you set up a listener for changes to the sensor, as opposed to a *pull* (polling) model.  I'll also assume that the callback happens on an off-UI thread (if it isn't, it should).

Since you are rotating the image I'll also assume that your source bitmap is a circular image like a needle on a dial, etc.

- Create a `View` subclass. I'll call it `SensorView`.  You will be doing the drawing yourself, so you don't really need an `ImageView`.
- Your sensor callback will need a reference to the activity or have some way to run the update on the UI thread.
- When your sensor fires, get the reading and set it on the view.

  ```
  actviity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          mSensorView.setReading(val);
      }
  });
  ```
- The `SensorView` will have a value for the reading, a `Bitmap` for the image, and a `Matrix` for transforming the bitmap.

  ```
  public class SensorView extends View {

      private float mReading;  // I use float as an example; use whatever your sensor device supports
      private Bitmap mBitmap;
      private Matrix mMatrix;
      private RectF mBitmapRect;
      private RectF mViewRect;

      public SensorView(Context context) {
          this(context, null);
      }

      public SensorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);

          // set up your Bitmap here; don't worry about scaling it yet
          mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.sensor_bitmap);

          mMatrix = new Matrix();
          mBitmapRect = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
          mViewRect = new RectF();
      }

      public void setReading(float reading) {
          mReading = reading;
          postInvalidate();   // refresh the display
      }

      @Override
      public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

          mViewRect.right = getWidth();
          mViewRect.bottom = getHeight();
          mMatrix.reset();

          // center and scale the image
          mMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mViewRect, ScaleToFit.CENTER);

          // do the rotation
          float theta = ... // compute angle based on mReading
          mMatrix.preRotate(theta, mBitmapRect.centerX(), mBitmapRect.centerY());

          // draw the bitmap with the matrix
          canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, null);
      }
  }
  ```

[edited after a bit of testing]

Comment: Okay, thank you! This seems way more straightforward than my "solution" and takes away the Handler. I'll test it soon!

Comment: Let me know if you run into problems. I will be testing it myself.

Comment: hey @felixd, I had a small typo (`Content`) and I was wrong about the non-UI thread, `setReading()` has to be run on the UI thread.  See my updated answer. If you have any trouble getting it working, update your question with all your new code and I'll look at it.

Comment: Why does it have to be called from there? The docs say: 
_Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event loop.

Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread. **This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread** only when this View is attached to a window._

Comment: So I thought it would be okay too, but Android Studio compiler complained because I was calling a method on a `View` from a non-UI thread.  They just assume that any method on a `View` has UI operations.  Maybe there's an annotation that can suppress that, have to investigate.

Comment: My compiles doesn't complain at all. Strange. But your code works (and apparently is fast)!